# Drag and Drop not working on shortcut or exefile

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Drag&Drop is working correctly when application is running. But when a file is dropped on application shortcut or exe.file, no drag&drop event is triggered just aaplication starts.

I created simple application in Visual Studio 2019, only Form1 with following adjustments

```
Form1.AllowDrop = True 

Private Sub Form1_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles MyBase.DragEnter
   If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) Then
      e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles MyBase.DragDrop
   Dim files() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
   Me.Text = files(0)
End Sub
```

Can you help me how to open my application with correct filename which is dropped on application icon/shortcut?

Thanks, Martin

Comment: `Me.Text = files(0)`: you should add some safety checks there. A file DragDrop also include folders, not just files. It depends on what you want to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only handles the drag and drop on the form itself (which can be done with any other control with `AllowDrop = True`). Dropping a file onto the application executable file (or shortcut) is a totally different thing; what it does is simply open the application normally but with a command-line argument passed to it (i.e., the file/folder path).

To retrieve that file/folder path, you can use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`, to read the command-line arguments, make sure it returns at least two elements (the first one is your application's executable path), and then display the second (or second to last) elements.

This should work:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    If args.Length > 1 Then Me.Text = args(1)
End Sub
```

If you drop multiple files onto your program's icon and you want to display them all, you can adjust the above code to something like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    For Each arg In args.Skip(1)
        ' Do something with `arg`.
    Next
End Sub
```